# If there is such a content, append it to the next element

Tags: jquery

I am checking content and I want to add button to right of button.

Following my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.btn-click').click(function(){
        $("p:contains(Test 2)").find('.view').append('<button>View-2</button>');

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button class="btn-click">Click Me</button>
  <p>Test 1</p> <button class="view">View</button>
  <p>Test 2</p> <button class="view">View</button>
  <p>Test 3</p> <button class="view">View</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `button` is not a child of your `p` then you have to use `.next('.view')` and not `.find('.view')`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.btn-click').click(function() {
    $("p:contains(Test 2)").parent().find('.view').append('<button>View-2</button>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-click">Click Me</button>
<div>
<p>Test 1</p> <span>Test Span</span> <button class="view">View</button>
</div>
<div>
<p>Test 2</p> <span>Test Span</span> <button class="view">View</button>
</div>
<div>
<p>Test 3</p> <span>Test Span</span> <button class="view">View</button>
</div>
```

Comment: <p>Test 1</p> <span>Test Span</span> <button class="view">View</button>
so if there is an html tag in between, how can i add it at the end? Sorry for asking the question wrong :D

Comment: @JFeel I've upgraded the Demo, I would wrap your p,span and button in a div tag and use the demo code

Comment: `.nextAll(".view").first()` if you want to find the "next" one that isn't the immediate-next, but changing your html can make this more reliable.